# How do I train a Transformer for translation on byte-pair encoding based embeddings, when the number of tokens for the same sentence is different?

Tags: machine-learning, encoding, nlp, word-embedding, transformer-model

I am implementing the paper [Attention Is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) from scratch in PyTorch. Currently, I want to implement a PyTorch Dataset class which will return an English word (or subword) as the input (X) and a German word (or subword) as the target (Y). In the paper, section 5.1, authors state that:

> We trained on the standard WMT 2014 English-German dataset consisting of about 4.5 million
> sentence pairs. Sentences were encoded using byte-pair encoding [3], which has a shared source-target vocabulary of about 37000 tokens.

I have found the original dataset [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/nmt/) and I also found [BPEmb](https://bpemb.h-its.org/), that is, pre-trained subword embeddings based on Byte-Pair Encoding (BPE) and trained on Wikipedia. My idea was to take an English sentence and its corresponding German sentence, transform them with BPEmb English embeddings and BPEmb German embeddings, respectively, and return the embeddings corresponding to the same word or subword as (X, Y) pair for training.

I experimented with BPEmb in the Python console and noticed the following thing which is confusing me:

The English sentence is:

> iron cement is a ready for use paste which is laid as a fillet by putty knife or finger in the mould edges ( corners ) of the steel ingot mould .

The corresponding German sentence is:

> iron cement ist eine gebrauchs ##AT##-##AT## fertige Paste , die mit einem Spachtel oder den Fingern als Hohlkehle in die Formecken ( Winkel ) der Stahlguss -Kokille aufgetragen wird .

**My problem comes from the fact that using BPEmb on the sentence in English results in 44 embeddings, while using BPEmb on the sentence in German results in 60 embeddings. I do not know which subword corresponds to which subword, since the number of embeddings doesn't match and thus I can't construct (X, Y) data pairs for training.** In other words, the number of X's is 44, while the number of Y's is 60, so I can't construct (X, Y) pairs since I don't have a one-to-one correspondence.

**Can anyone tell me how is BPE (and embedding) implemented in the paper? What am I missing here?** As a side note, if I am going to make my implementation easier by using some other pretrained embedding (which outputs a single embedding for a single word), I'm open to that as well.